# ¿Por qué mi programa JavaScript intercala los elementos en posición par y no par en su funcionamiento?

Tags: javascript

El Funcionamiento de mi lista no es el adecuado ya que al agregar un elemento este primero sí tiene la capacidad de ser marcado para posteriormente ser borrado pero al agregar un segundo elemento ya el primero pierde la funcionalidad y el segundo  sí la tiene; pero al agregar un tercer elemento nuevamente tanto el primero como el último agregado sí tienen o les regresa la funcionalidad; así agregando un cuarto elemento ya solo el segundo y el último que es el cuarto sí tienen funcionalidad osea que está intercalando como si se tratase de este caso para el cual el uno es la funcion activa 101 a 0101.

Éste es mi código (la lista que falla se puede ver en la parte superior izquierda de la pantalla, donde se pueden agregar datos):

```js
//variables
(function(){
  // Accediendo A Elementos Y creando Una Variable De Acceso Directo A Ellos
  var Sub_list = document.getElementById("Sub_list"),
      List = document.getElementById('List'),
      Writted = document.getElementById('Writted'),
      sec = document.getElementById("sctn"),
      BasuraElimn = document.getElementById("BasuraElimn");
  Btn_List = document.getElementById('Btn_List');

  //funciones De Creacion De Elementos
  var Input_Tarea = function(){
    Home_work = Writted.value;
    Nuev_li = document.createElement("li");
    Nuev_a = document.createElement("a");
    Nuev_ol = document.createElement("ol");
    Nuev_Del =document.createElement("div");
    content_Nuev_Del = document.createTextNode("X");
    contenido = document.createTextNode(Home_work);


    //validacion,Colocacion De Los Elementos En Su Respectivo Lugar , Poniendo Clases Y Referencias A Los Objetos.
    while(Home_work === ""){
      Writted.setAttribute("placeholder", "Add Something!!");
      Writted.setAttribute("class", "error");
      Writted.className = "error";
      return false;
    }

    Nuev_Del.setAttribute("class", "borrar");
    //sele agrega clase y id al div creado Nuev_Del
    Nuev_Del.setAttribute("id", "borrar");
    // Agregamos los estilos paja a a
    Nuev_a.setAttribute("class", "paja");
    // Agregamos el contenido al enlace
    Nuev_a.appendChild(contenido);
    // Le establecemos un atributo href
    Nuev_a.setAttribute("href", "#");
    // Se agraga el contenido de la X a el mini div
    Nuev_Del.appendChild(content_Nuev_Del);
    // Se le agrega el div para borrar al elemento
    Nuev_a.appendChild(Nuev_Del);  
    // Agrergamos el enlace (a) a la nueva tarea (li)
    Nuev_li.appendChild(Nuev_a);
    // Agregamos la nueva tarea a la lista
    List.appendChild(Nuev_li);
    // Agregamos el ul con un ol dentro de el li
    Writted.value = "";
    //Reestablesimos el valor de writted
    Writted.setAttribute("class", "inwrite");
    //Reestablesimos la clase de writted


    //agrega una clase para marcar el elemento seleccionado a editar , borrar o no borrar.

    for (var k = 0; k <= List.children.length -1; k++)
    {

      List.children[k].addEventListener("click" , function(){

        if(this.className === "ViewDelett0element")

        {
          this.setAttribute("class", "");
        } 
        else
        {
          this.setAttribute("class", "ViewDelett0element");
        }

      }

                                       );


    }
  };//cierre de la Mega variable inpput tarea


  var RunTheSelectionAndDeselectionOfListaElement0s = function () {


    List.children[k].addEventListener("click" , function(){

      if(this.className === "ViewDelett0element")

      {
        this.setAttribute("class", "");
      } 

      else
      {
        this.setAttribute("class", "ViewDelett0element");
      }

    }

                                     );

  };



  var comprobarInput = function(){
    Writted.className = "";
    Writted.setAttribute("placeholder", "Add Your List");
    Writted.setAttribute("class", "inwrite");

  };



  var eleminarTarea = function eliminarElementosDeClase(list, ViewDelett0element) {
    //Obtener todos los hijos que coinciden con el nombre de la clase
    LosHijitosDeApa = List.getElementsByClassName("ViewDelett0element");

    //Loop para c/u
    var lengeted = LosHijitosDeApa.length;
    for (var i = lengeted-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      //Borrar 1 elemento (parándose en el padre)
      LosHijitosDeApa[i].parentNode.removeChild(LosHijitosDeApa[i]);
    }
  };
  // Eventos Eventos Eventos 




  var SelectoBorrartds = function() {for (var k = 0; k <= List.children.length -1; k++)

  {

    List.children[k].addEventListener("click" , RunTheSelectionAndDeselectionOfListaElement0s); 

  }
                                    };

  (function(){
    // Seleccionar elementos para ser borrados
    for (var k = 0; k <= List.children.length -1; k++)

    {

      List.children[k].addEventListener("click" , SelectoBorrartds); 

    }}());

  // Agregar Tarea
  Btn_List.addEventListener("click", Input_Tarea);

  // Comprobar Input
  Writted.addEventListener("click", comprobarInput);

  // Borrando Elementos de la lista
  BasuraElimn.addEventListener("click", eleminarTarea);



}());
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding:0px; 
}
.diva{ 
  position: relative;
  background-color:#0175A6;/*color de fondo de encabezado de barra buscador*/
  border-right: 0px solid black; /*borde de buscador*/
  border-left: 0px solid black; /*borde de buscador*/
  border-top: 1px solid black; /*borde de buscador*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid black; /*borde de buscador*/
  width: 100%;    
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right:auto;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0px 8px 0px ;
  height: 2%;
  max-height:50px;
  float: left;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}   
.diva:hover{
  border-top: 1px solid black; /*borde de buscador*/
  background-color: #6CABB0; 
  height: 1%;
  -o-transition: all .6s;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s;
  transition: all .6s;
}

.pap{
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  max-width: 20%;
  width:100%;
  min-width: 10%;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.stylis{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  float: right;
  min-width: 48px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 30px 20px 20px 0px;
  background-color: #DFFFFF;/*Color de fondo de buscador*/
  border: 2px solid black;/*borde de buscador*/
  border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
  padding: .5px .5px .5px .5px   }

.stylis:hover{
  border-top: 3px solid brown;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-right: 3px solid brown;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-left: 3px solid brown;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-bottom: 3px solid brown;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-radius: 22px;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  height: 23px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #1D1D24;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.stylis:focus
{
  border-top: 2.7px solid brown;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-right: 2.7px solid brown;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-left: 2.7px solid brown;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-bottom: 2.7px solid brown;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.divs{
  position: static;
  width: 9%;
  min-width: 55px;
  max-width:190px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #3D888A;
  border-top: 3px solid black;/*ancho de el borde y color*/ 
  border-right: 2px solid black;/*ancho de el borde y color*/ 
  border-left: 2px solid black;/*ancho de el borde y color*/ 
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;/*ancho de el borde y color*/ 
  padding: 0px 7px 0px 0px ;/*ancho de el contenedor azul*/
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 0px ;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px ; /*Espacio con respecto al cuerpo de la pag*/
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.divs:hover{
  background-color:#10A0DB; 
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}

ul li ul li:hover{
  padding: auto;
  background-color: #434343;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: auto;  
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}

div ul li ul{
  display: none;
}

div ul li:hover > ul{
  display: block;
}


ul li ul li{
  text-align: center; 
  border-radius:20px ;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width:180px;
  width: auto;
  color: black;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px ;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-color: #E34200 ;
  font-size:65%;
  margin: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid black;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.ViewDelett0element{
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  margin:2px 6px 7px 8px;/*Separacion entre elementos de la lista*/
  border:3.5px solid #983012;/*Color de el borde de el contenedor de elemento de lista*/ 
  width: auto;
  min-width:50px; 
  max-width:110px;
  font-weight:bold; 
  font-size: 90%;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.ViewDelett0element:hover{
  overflow:hidden;
  font-size: 92%;
  border:4px solid #983008;
  color: red;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.paja{
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:black;/*color de fondo de el elemento de la lista*/
  display:block;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  color:#fffff9;/*color de la fuente de los elementos de la lista*/
  text-align: center;
  margin:2px 6px 7px 8px;/*Separacion entre elementos de la lista*/
  border:3.5px solid #236600;/*Color de el borde de el contenedor de elemento de lista*/ 
  width: auto;
  min-width:50px; 
  max-width:110px;
  font-weight:bold; 
  font-size: 90%;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.paja:hover{
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:black;/*color de fondo de el elemento de la lista*/
  font-size: 92%;
  border:4px solid #983008;
  color: #fff043;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  -o-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
}


#tareaInput{
  padding: auto;
  margin-left: 1px;
  width: 65%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border:3px solid black;
}

.cuerpo{
  background-color:#529191;
}

.ping{
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  background-color:black;
  display:block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 12.5%;
  position: relative;
  border:5px solid #E60; 
  width:5px ;
  padding: 3px 15px 1px 10px;
  margin: auto;
  float: right;
  right: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s;
  -o-transition: all .7s;
  transition: all .7s;
}

.ping:hover{
  font-size:17px ;
  -webkit-transition: all .8s;
  -o-transition: all .8s;
  transition: all .8s;
}

.minimas{
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 10px;
  padding: auto;
  border-radius: 70px;
  font-size: auto;
}

.inwrite{
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-right:20px;
  margin-left:3%;
  margin-bottom:8px; 
  min-width: 28px;
  max-width:125px;
  width: 100%; 
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.inwrite:hover{
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  -o-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.inwrite:focus{
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  text-align: center;
}

.error{
  background-color: #ffff99;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:red;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-right:20px;
  margin-left:4.4%;
  margin-bottom:8px; 
  min-width: 28px;
  max-width:125px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.error:hover{
  background-color: #fffe69;
  font-weight: arial;
  color:gray;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-right:20px;
  margin-left:4.4%;
  margin-bottom:8px; 
  min-width: 28px;
  max-width:125px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.Sub_divi{
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: #000 0 4px;
  box-shadow: 22px;
  cursor: move;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px ;
  width: 9%;
  max-width:180px;
  min-width:60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px ;
  margin-left:30px; 
  margin-top: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.Sub_divi:hover{
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  -o-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
  background-color: #282623;
}

ul>div{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4.5%;
  min-width: 30px;
  max-width:180px;
  height: 3.5%;
  min-height: 22.5px;
  max-height:95px;
  float: left;
  background-color: orange;
  border-top: 2px solid #0D0E29;
  border-right: 2px solid #0D0E29;
  border-left: 2px solid #0D0E29;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0D0E29;
  padding: 0px 7px 0px 0px ;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px ;
  list-style: none;
  overflow:hidden; 
  margin: 0% 0% 0% 1.5px;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  -o-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
}

ul>div:hover{
  padding: 0px 0px 100px 0px ;/*Pestañas Naranja De Parte De Arriba*/
  margin: 0% 0% 0% 4px;
  border-top: 2.5px solid #000;
  border-right: 2.5px solid #000;
  border-left: 2.5px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 2.5px solid #000;
  background-color: gold;
  text-shadow: #000 0 10px;
  box-shadow: 22px;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  -o-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
}


.intrMessages_General{
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;/*color de la fuente de los elementos de la lista*/
  background-color: #2E7D96;/*color de fondo de el elemento de la lista*/
  border-top: 3px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-right: 3px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-left: 3px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-bottom:3px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px ;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight:bold; 
  font-size: 90%;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow:hidden; 
  margin-top: 170px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.intrMessages_General2{
  position: static;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 550px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  color: black;/*color de la fuente de los elementos de la lista*/
  background-color: white;/*color de fondo de el elemento de la lista*/
  border-top: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-right: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-left: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px ;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight:bold; 
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-bottom:;
  margin-right:;
  margin-left:22px;
  font-size: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow:hidden; 
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.intrMessages_Generalbotoncompartir{
  position: static;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  color: black;/*color de la fuente de los elementos de la lista*/
  background-color: gold;/*color de fondo de el elemento de la lista*/
  border-top: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-right: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-left: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px ;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight:bold; 
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom:;
  margin-right:;
  margin-left:4px;
  font-size:;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.intrMessages_Generalbotoncompartir:hover{
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.intrMessages_Generalbotonbuscar{
  position: static;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  color: black;/*color de la fuente de los elementos de la lista*/
  background-color: gold;/*color de fondo de el elemento de la lista*/
  border-top: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-right: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-left: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px ;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight:bold; 
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom:;
  margin-right:;
  margin-left:20px;
  font-size:;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.intrMessages_Generalbotonbuscar:hover{
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.borrar{
  font-size: 9px;
  margin-top:3.5px; 
  margin-right:3px; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #972A29;
  float: right;
  color: white;
  background-color: #972A29;
  width: 20px;
  height: 13px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.borrar:hover{
  border: 2px solid #73201F;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}

.icon-trash{
  color: black;
  background-color: #D67A6F;
  padding: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: block;
  position: static;
  font-size: 30px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  overflow:hidden; 
  margin: 0% 0% 0% 5px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all .8s;
  -o-transition: all .8s;
  transition: all .8s;
}


.icon-trash:hover::before{
  background-color: #D67A6F;
  font-size: 43px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.icon-trash:active::before{
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: gold;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border: 7px solid #D67A6F;
  font-size: 43px;
  -webkit-transition: all .04;
  -o-transition: all .04;
  transition: all .04s;
}
```

```html
<body class="cuerpo">

  <header>
    <div class="diva">
      <div class="pap">
        <input type="text" placeHolder="  Que Quieres Buscar" maxlength="40" name="dance" class="stylis"> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section id="sctn">
    <div class="divs">
      <ul id="List">
        <!--Aqui se agrega dinamicamente los elementos de la lista-->
      </ul>



      <li class="ping" id="Btn_List">
        <a class="minimas" src="" id="Btn_List" name="botton">+</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <input id="Writted" type="text/number" class="inwrite" maxlength="60" placeholder="Add More!" autofocus>
      </li>

    </div>

    <button id="BasuraElimn" class="icon-trash">
    </button>

  </section>

  <ul>
    <div img src="#" alt="imgen" ><div></div></div>
    <div img src="#" alt="imgen" ><div></div></div>
    <div img src="#" alt="imgen" ><div></div></div>
    <div img src="#" alt="imgen" ><div></div></div>
  </ul>

  <div class="intrMessages_General">
    <input class="intrMessages_General2" placeholder="  Hey What´s Up!!">
    <button class="intrMessages_Generalbotoncompartir">Compartir
    </button>
    <button class="intrMessages_Generalbotonbuscar">Buscar
    </button>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Hola Emanuel, asi como esta la pregunta falta (o esta tapado) el contexto para responderla, por favor, formatea bien el codigo y exlicanos donde se produce el problema ya que es un codigo bastante largo. Gracias.

Comment: te referis a los elementos a los cuales accedo en el dom o no he comprendido la cuestion?

Comment: Si hace falta un ejemplo, agregalos. y ademas a explicar el problema, la frase "intercala el funcionamiento de los elementos" no se entiende bien.

Comment: esta bien , entonces agregare mi parte de la pagina completa , se daran cuenta que en el programa no existen errores y ademas en la lista que estara de lado izquierdo al momento de seleccionar los elementos se intercala el poder utilizar su funcion de seleccionado despues de agregar uno mas

Comment: rayos no pude subirlo esque es toda una pagina y son muchos caracteres

Comment: Pon las partes relevantes, no toda la pagina.

Comment: rayos pondre solo el html al que accede el dom ya que esta largo si es que se incluye el css al que el javascript cambia

Comment: <section id="sctn">
<div class="divs">
<ul id="List">
<!--Aqui se agrega dinamicamente los elementos de la lista-->
</ul>



<li class="ping" id="Btn_List">
<a class="minimas" src="" id="Btn_List" name="botton">+</a>
</li>

Comment: lo anterior es la parte mas relevante ya que hay se agrega o crea dinamicamente los elementos html etc

Comment: Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) en el Centro de Ayuda. Tal y como está ahora mismo la pregunta no se puede reproducir el problema (falta código HTML que hace que el JS lancé errores).

Comment: gracias lo are ahoramismo

Comment: exelente aprendi algo nuevo (= ya e editado mi pregunta y como la plantie , bienen los 3 codigod , html, css y js separados , no los inclui en el html con sus respetivas links ya que me solo los he incluido dentro de su estiqueta style y scrip a css y js respectivament

Comment: @EmmanuelRuiz Intenté varias veces entender cuál era el problema, pero no pude. Además, son muchas líneas de código para algo que seguramente podrías reproducir en pocas líneas... Realmente, ¿podrás [edit] la pregunta para enfocar en cuál es el tema por el que consultás? ... Ayudanos a ayudarte!!

Comment: @Mariano muchas gracias ya he editado la manera en que plante el problema , mi problema es exactamente con una lista dentro de la pagina la cual tiene el for que por sieto anteriormente me has ayudado el cual recorre desde el ultimo hasta el primer elemento para asu vez agregar una funcion para permitir tanto borrar como marcar a cada elemento en la lista , la cosa es que esta funcion parese muerta con cada elemento agregado ya que al mas reciente si la tiene y el anterior ya no pero al poner uno mas ese que perdio la funcion la recupera y el nuevo tambien pero el penultimo la pierde asi suces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al principio pensé que el problema era que había IDs repetidos, pero luego me di cuenta de que ese no era el caso (aunque los hay, eso no afecta a la ejecución). **El verdadero problema está en cómo asocias los controladores del evento click: cada vez que creas un elemento y lo añades a la lista se asocian los controladores a TODOS los elementos de la lista** y no sólo al elemento que has creado nuevo.

Qué pasa entonces: el evento es el que abre/cierra el modo de borrado dependiendo del estado en el que estuviera antes. Al asociar múltiples veces el mismo controlador, lo que haces es que se va a ejecutar tantas veces como se haya asociado. Y ese es el problema: si se ha asociado un número impar de veces, cambiará el estado; si se ha asociado un número par de veces, las ejecuciones se contrarrestarán y quedará el mismo estado (como si no hubiese ocurrido nada).

Esto es un ejemplo de la ejecución actual:

1. El usuario escribe texto y pulsa en el +

   1. Se crea el elemento 1
   2. Se entra en el bucle for para todos los elementos de la lista

      1. Se asocia el controlador del click al elemento 1 que llamaré elem1_click1
2. El usuario pulsa sobre la X del elemento 1:

   1. Se lanza el controlador elem1_click1 y se expande el elemento
3. El usuario escribe texto y pulsa en el +

   1. Se crea el elemento 2
   2. Se entra en el bucle for para todos los elementos de la lista

      1. Se asocia el controlador del click al elemento 1 que llamaré elem1_click2
      2. Se asocia el controlador del click al elemento 2 que llamaré elem2_click1
4. El usuario pulsa sobre la X del elemento 1:

   1. Se lanza el controlador elem1_click1 y se expande el elemento
   2. Se lanza el controlador elem1_click2 y se cierra el elemento (pareciendo que nada ha pasado, cuando realmente han ocurrido dos acciones)
5. El usuario escribe texto y pulsa en el +

   1. Se crea el elemento 3
   2. Se entra en el bucle for para todos los elementos de la lista

      1. Se asocia el controlador del click al elemento 1 que llamaré elem1_click3
      2. Se asocia el controlador del click al elemento 2 que llamaré elem2_click2
      3. Se asocia el controlador del click al elemento 3 que llamaré elem3_click1
6. El usuario pulsa sobre la X del elemento 1:

   1. Se lanza el controlador elem1_click1 y se expande el elemento
   2. Se lanza el controlador elem1_click2 y se cierra el elemento
   3. Se lanza el controlador elem1_click3 y se expande el elemento (pareciendo que sólo ha pasado una vez, cuando realmente han ocurrido tres acciones: abrir-cerrar-abrir)
7. ....

Una posible solución sería asociar el controlador del evento click sólo al elemento que se crea en lugar de a todos los elementos (con un `for`). La idea sería cambiar este código:

```
for (var k = 0; k <= List.children.length -1; k++)
{

  List.children[k].addEventListener("click" , function(){

    if(this.className === "ViewDelett0element")

    {
      this.setAttribute("class", "");
    } 
    else
    {
      this.setAttribute("class", "ViewDelett0element");
    }

  }

                                   );


}
```

por este otro:

```
  Nuev_li.addEventListener("click" , function(){
    if(this.className === "ViewDelett0element") {
      this.setAttribute("class", "");
    } else {
      this.setAttribute("class", "ViewDelett0element");
    }
  });
```

Y ahora ya funciona sin problemas:

> Nota: "sin problemas" realmente significa "sin ese problema"< el código puede presentar otros problemas diferentes que no entran dentro de la pregunta en sí.

```js
//variables
(function(){
  // Accediendo A Elementos Y creando Una Variable De Acceso Directo A Ellos
  var Sub_list = document.getElementById("Sub_list"),
      List = document.getElementById('List'),
      Writted = document.getElementById('Writted'),
      sec = document.getElementById("sctn"),
      BasuraElimn = document.getElementById("BasuraElimn");
  Btn_List = document.getElementById('Btn_List');

  //funciones De Creacion De Elementos
  var Input_Tarea = function(){
    Home_work = Writted.value;
    Nuev_li = document.createElement("li");
    Nuev_a = document.createElement("a");
    Nuev_ol = document.createElement("ol");
    Nuev_Del =document.createElement("div");
    content_Nuev_Del = document.createTextNode("X");
    contenido = document.createTextNode(Home_work);


    //validacion,Colocacion De Los Elementos En Su Respectivo Lugar , Poniendo Clases Y Referencias A Los Objetos.
    while(Home_work === ""){
      Writted.setAttribute("placeholder", "Add Something!!");
      Writted.setAttribute("class", "error");
      Writted.className = "error";
      return false;
    }

    Nuev_Del.setAttribute("class", "borrar");
    //sele agrega clase y id al div creado Nuev_Del
    Nuev_Del.setAttribute("id", "borrar");
    // Agregamos los estilos paja a a
    Nuev_a.setAttribute("class", "paja");
    // Agregamos el contenido al enlace
    Nuev_a.appendChild(contenido);
    // Le establecemos un atributo href
    Nuev_a.setAttribute("href", "#");
    // Se agraga el contenido de la X a el mini div
    Nuev_Del.appendChild(content_Nuev_Del);
    // Se le agrega el div para borrar al elemento
    Nuev_a.appendChild(Nuev_Del);  
    // Agrergamos el enlace (a) a la nueva tarea (li)
    Nuev_li.appendChild(Nuev_a);
    // Agregamos la nueva tarea a la lista
    List.appendChild(Nuev_li);
    // Agregamos el ul con un ol dentro de el li
    Writted.value = "";
    //Reestablesimos el valor de writted
    Writted.setAttribute("class", "inwrite");
    //Reestablesimos la clase de writted


      Nuev_li.addEventListener("click" , function(){
        if(this.className === "ViewDelett0element") {
          this.setAttribute("class", "");
        } else {
          this.setAttribute("class", "ViewDelett0element");
        }
      });
    
  };//cierre de la Mega variable inpput tarea


  var RunTheSelectionAndDeselectionOfListaElement0s = function () {
    List.children[k].addEventListener("click" , function(){
      if(this.className === "ViewDelett0element") {
        this.setAttribute("class", "");
      } else {
        this.setAttribute("class", "ViewDelett0element");
      }
    });
  };

  var comprobarInput = function(){
    Writted.className = "";
    Writted.setAttribute("placeholder", "Add Your List");
    Writted.setAttribute("class", "inwrite");
  };

  var eleminarTarea = function eliminarElementosDeClase(list, ViewDelett0element) {
    //Obtener todos los hijos que coinciden con el nombre de la clase
    LosHijitosDeApa = List.getElementsByClassName("ViewDelett0element");

    //Loop para c/u
    var lengeted = LosHijitosDeApa.length;
    for (var i = lengeted-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      //Borrar 1 elemento (parándose en el padre)
      LosHijitosDeApa[i].parentNode.removeChild(LosHijitosDeApa[i]);
    }
  };

  // Eventos Eventos Eventos 
  var SelectoBorrartds = function() {
    for (var k = 0; k <= List.children.length -1; k++) {
      List.children[k].addEventListener("click" , RunTheSelectionAndDeselectionOfListaElement0s); 
    }
  };

  (function(){
    // Seleccionar elementos para ser borrados
    for (var k = 0; k <= List.children.length -1; k++) {
      List.children[k].addEventListener("click" , SelectoBorrartds); 
    }
  }());

  // Agregar Tarea
  Btn_List.addEventListener("click", Input_Tarea);

  // Comprobar Input
  Writted.addEventListener("click", comprobarInput);

  // Borrando Elementos de la lista
  BasuraElimn.addEventListener("click", eleminarTarea);

}());
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding:0px; 
}
.diva{ 
  position: relative;
  background-color:#0175A6;/*color de fondo de encabezado de barra buscador*/
  border-right: 0px solid black; /*borde de buscador*/
  border-left: 0px solid black; /*borde de buscador*/
  border-top: 1px solid black; /*borde de buscador*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid black; /*borde de buscador*/
  width: 100%;    
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right:auto;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0px 8px 0px ;
  height: 2%;
  max-height:50px;
  float: left;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}   
.diva:hover{
  border-top: 1px solid black; /*borde de buscador*/
  background-color: #6CABB0; 
  height: 1%;
  -o-transition: all .6s;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s;
  transition: all .6s;
}

.pap{
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  max-width: 20%;
  width:100%;
  min-width: 10%;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.stylis{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  float: right;
  min-width: 48px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 30px 20px 20px 0px;
  background-color: #DFFFFF;/*Color de fondo de buscador*/
  border: 2px solid black;/*borde de buscador*/
  border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
  padding: .5px .5px .5px .5px   }

.stylis:hover{
  border-top: 3px solid brown;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-right: 3px solid brown;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-left: 3px solid brown;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-bottom: 3px solid brown;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-radius: 22px;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  height: 23px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #1D1D24;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.stylis:focus
{
  border-top: 2.7px solid brown;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-right: 2.7px solid brown;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-left: 2.7px solid brown;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-bottom: 2.7px solid brown;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.divs{
  position: static;
  width: 9%;
  min-width: 55px;
  max-width:190px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #3D888A;
  border-top: 3px solid black;/*ancho de el borde y color*/ 
  border-right: 2px solid black;/*ancho de el borde y color*/ 
  border-left: 2px solid black;/*ancho de el borde y color*/ 
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;/*ancho de el borde y color*/ 
  padding: 0px 7px 0px 0px ;/*ancho de el contenedor azul*/
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 0px ;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px ; /*Espacio con respecto al cuerpo de la pag*/
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.divs:hover{
  background-color:#10A0DB; 
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}

ul li ul li:hover{
  padding: auto;
  background-color: #434343;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: auto;  
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}

div ul li ul{
  display: none;
}

div ul li:hover > ul{
  display: block;
}


ul li ul li{
  text-align: center; 
  border-radius:20px ;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width:180px;
  width: auto;
  color: black;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px ;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-color: #E34200 ;
  font-size:65%;
  margin: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid black;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.ViewDelett0element{
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  margin:2px 6px 7px 8px;/*Separacion entre elementos de la lista*/
  border:3.5px solid #983012;/*Color de el borde de el contenedor de elemento de lista*/ 
  width: auto;
  min-width:50px; 
  max-width:110px;
  font-weight:bold; 
  font-size: 90%;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.ViewDelett0element:hover{
  overflow:hidden;
  font-size: 92%;
  border:4px solid #983008;
  color: red;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.paja{
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:black;/*color de fondo de el elemento de la lista*/
  display:block;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  color:#fffff9;/*color de la fuente de los elementos de la lista*/
  text-align: center;
  margin:2px 6px 7px 8px;/*Separacion entre elementos de la lista*/
  border:3.5px solid #236600;/*Color de el borde de el contenedor de elemento de lista*/ 
  width: auto;
  min-width:50px; 
  max-width:110px;
  font-weight:bold; 
  font-size: 90%;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.paja:hover{
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:black;/*color de fondo de el elemento de la lista*/
  font-size: 92%;
  border:4px solid #983008;
  color: #fff043;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  -o-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
}


#tareaInput{
  padding: auto;
  margin-left: 1px;
  width: 65%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border:3px solid black;
}

.cuerpo{
  background-color:#529191;
}

.ping{
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  background-color:black;
  display:block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 12.5%;
  position: relative;
  border:5px solid #E60; 
  width:5px ;
  padding: 3px 15px 1px 10px;
  margin: auto;
  float: right;
  right: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s;
  -o-transition: all .7s;
  transition: all .7s;
}

.ping:hover{
  font-size:17px ;
  -webkit-transition: all .8s;
  -o-transition: all .8s;
  transition: all .8s;
}

.minimas{
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 10px;
  padding: auto;
  border-radius: 70px;
  font-size: auto;
}

.inwrite{
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-right:20px;
  margin-left:3%;
  margin-bottom:8px; 
  min-width: 28px;
  max-width:125px;
  width: 100%; 
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.inwrite:hover{
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  -o-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.inwrite:focus{
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  text-align: center;
}

.error{
  background-color: #ffff99;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:red;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-right:20px;
  margin-left:4.4%;
  margin-bottom:8px; 
  min-width: 28px;
  max-width:125px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.error:hover{
  background-color: #fffe69;
  font-weight: arial;
  color:gray;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-right:20px;
  margin-left:4.4%;
  margin-bottom:8px; 
  min-width: 28px;
  max-width:125px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.Sub_divi{
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: #000 0 4px;
  box-shadow: 22px;
  cursor: move;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px ;
  width: 9%;
  max-width:180px;
  min-width:60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px ;
  margin-left:30px; 
  margin-top: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.Sub_divi:hover{
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  -o-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
  background-color: #282623;
}

ul>div{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4.5%;
  min-width: 30px;
  max-width:180px;
  height: 3.5%;
  min-height: 22.5px;
  max-height:95px;
  float: left;
  background-color: orange;
  border-top: 2px solid #0D0E29;
  border-right: 2px solid #0D0E29;
  border-left: 2px solid #0D0E29;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0D0E29;
  padding: 0px 7px 0px 0px ;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px ;
  list-style: none;
  overflow:hidden; 
  margin: 0% 0% 0% 1.5px;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  -o-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
}

ul>div:hover{
  padding: 0px 0px 100px 0px ;/*Pestañas Naranja De Parte De Arriba*/
  margin: 0% 0% 0% 4px;
  border-top: 2.5px solid #000;
  border-right: 2.5px solid #000;
  border-left: 2.5px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 2.5px solid #000;
  background-color: gold;
  text-shadow: #000 0 10px;
  box-shadow: 22px;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  -o-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
}


.intrMessages_General{
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;/*color de la fuente de los elementos de la lista*/
  background-color: #2E7D96;/*color de fondo de el elemento de la lista*/
  border-top: 3px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-right: 3px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-left: 3px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-bottom:3px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px ;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight:bold; 
  font-size: 90%;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow:hidden; 
  margin-top: 170px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.intrMessages_General2{
  position: static;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 550px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  color: black;/*color de la fuente de los elementos de la lista*/
  background-color: white;/*color de fondo de el elemento de la lista*/
  border-top: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-right: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-left: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px ;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight:bold; 
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-bottom:;
  margin-right:;
  margin-left:22px;
  font-size: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow:hidden; 
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.intrMessages_Generalbotoncompartir{
  position: static;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  color: black;/*color de la fuente de los elementos de la lista*/
  background-color: gold;/*color de fondo de el elemento de la lista*/
  border-top: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-right: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-left: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px ;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight:bold; 
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom:;
  margin-right:;
  margin-left:4px;
  font-size:;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.intrMessages_Generalbotoncompartir:hover{
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.intrMessages_Generalbotonbuscar{
  position: static;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  color: black;/*color de la fuente de los elementos de la lista*/
  background-color: gold;/*color de fondo de el elemento de la lista*/
  border-top: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-right: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-left: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0D0E29;/*ancho de el corde y color*/ 
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px ;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight:bold; 
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom:;
  margin-right:;
  margin-left:20px;
  font-size:;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.intrMessages_Generalbotonbuscar:hover{
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.borrar{
  font-size: 9px;
  margin-top:3.5px; 
  margin-right:3px; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #972A29;
  float: right;
  color: white;
  background-color: #972A29;
  width: 20px;
  height: 13px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.borrar:hover{
  border: 2px solid #73201F;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}

.icon-trash{
  color: black;
  background-color: #D67A6F;
  padding: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: block;
  position: static;
  font-size: 30px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  overflow:hidden; 
  margin: 0% 0% 0% 5px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all .8s;
  -o-transition: all .8s;
  transition: all .8s;
}


.icon-trash:hover::before{
  background-color: #D67A6F;
  font-size: 43px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.icon-trash:active::before{
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: gold;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border: 7px solid #D67A6F;
  font-size: 43px;
  -webkit-transition: all .04;
  -o-transition: all .04;
  transition: all .04s;
}
```

```html
<body class="cuerpo">

  <header>
    <div class="diva">
      <div class="pap">
        <input type="text" placeHolder="  Que Quieres Buscar" maxlength="40" name="dance" class="stylis"> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section id="sctn">
    <div class="divs">
      <ul id="List">
        <!--Aqui se agrega dinamicamente los elementos de la lista-->
      </ul>
      <li class="ping" id="Btn_List">
        <a class="minimas" src="" id="Btn_List" name="botton">+</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input id="Writted" type="text/number" class="inwrite" maxlength="60" placeholder="Add More!" autofocus>
      </li>
    </div>
    <button id="BasuraElimn" class="icon-trash"></button>
  </section>

  <ul>
    <div img src="#" alt="imgen" ><div></div></div>
    <div img src="#" alt="imgen" ><div></div></div>
    <div img src="#" alt="imgen" ><div></div></div>
    <div img src="#" alt="imgen" ><div></div></div>
  </ul>

  <div class="intrMessages_General">
    <input class="intrMessages_General2" placeholder="  Hey What´s Up!!">
    <button class="intrMessages_Generalbotoncompartir">Compartir
    </button>
    <button class="intrMessages_Generalbotonbuscar">Buscar
    </button>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Quedo sinceramente agradecido por tu ayuda y mas que nada por la enseñanza ya que jamas pude deducir que hacia eso mi función ya que no pensé que sobre escribía o colocaba esa función a el elemento seleccionado , ya comprendo varios errores pasados con esto , Te veo como un Mark Sukerber ayudandome XD lo cual me hace sentir mas motivado , gracias por tu labor altruista